# How should I use result of SQL query in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> Below code is from Course.aspx

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="ShowImage.ashx?id={?}" alt="" Width="600px" Height="450px" />
```

> Below code is from CourseDetail.cs

```
var courseid = Request.QueryString["courseid"].ToString();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Course where CourseID=@CourseID";
string[] name = { "@CourseID" };
string[] value = { courseid };
DataTable dt = DataBase.SQLselect(sql, name, value);
```

`ShowImage.ashx?id={courseid}` this code works great. I check with any current number suc as `ShowImage.ashx?id=5.`

Now I want to know how I shloud call `CourseID` in `Course.aspx` :

`ImageUrl="ShowImage.ashx?id={CourseID}` ??

Comment: I thought you said the code works great? Whats the problem...

Comment: I mean that when I write  `ShowImage.ashx?id=5 ` manually , it works,  But I need to use  `CourseID ` such as  `ShowImage.ashx?id={Call CourseID} `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In aspx side put ID to your element.

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgCourse" alt="" Width="600px" Height="450px" />
```

Than in .cs side call your object.

```
imgCourse.ImageUrl="ShowImage.ashx?id=" + dt.courseID.ToString();
```

Comment: But genereally Dont you know how can I write as I said ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to bind data in aspx side? If yes, your element has to be in repeter,listview etc. And you can bind ID from datasource which is already binded to repeter. For this kind of single element its easy and efficient to set data in .cs side.

Comment: here I dont need repeater.
For example you sign in facebook.com and when you go to your Profil page you can see your data (forexample profilphoto).